# Como hacer un ViewPager en Android Studio con tres vistas pero que aparente vistas ilimitadas

Tags: vistas, viewpager

Lo que pretendo es mostrar una información a través de un ViewPager de un modo similar a un calendario, pudiendo desde el inicio ir hacia delante o hacia atrás y sin saber cuantas vistas se van a mostrar. Lo que se me ocurre es que realmente haya tres vistas, partir de la posición central y que el contenido se vaya actualizando. Adjunto el código que he usado y que hace lo que pretendo pero si intento pasar las vistas muy rápido se para durante un instante. Aquí, para probar, el número de vistas está limitado porque paso la información a través de un ArrayList, pero en la realidad no debería ser así.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private ViewPager viewPager;
    List<String> TextoDeArchivo = new ArrayList<>();

    TextView textoIgualAlFragment;

    int contador = 1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        textoIgualAlFragment = findViewById(R.id.texto_fragment2);

        iniciarArrayList();
        initViewPager2();

        viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

            }
            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                //Your code here
                if( position > 1 ) contador++;
                if( position < 1 ) contador--;
            }
            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
                // Los valores de state son 1, 2, 0
                if( state == 0 ) {
                    initViewPager2();
                    viewPager.setCurrentItem(1);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private void initViewPager2() {
        viewPager = findViewById(R.id.viewpager);

        List<Fragment> simpleTabList = new ArrayList<>();
        simpleTabList.add( new ContenidoFragment().newContenido( TextoDeArchivo.get(contador-1) ) );
        simpleTabList.add( new ContenidoFragment().newContenido( TextoDeArchivo.get(contador) ) );
        simpleTabList.add( new ContenidoFragment().newContenido( TextoDeArchivo.get(contador+1) ) );
        viewPager.setAdapter( new TabsSetup(simpleTabList, getSupportFragmentManager() ) );
    }

    public void iniciarArrayList() {
        TextoDeArchivo.add( "uno" );
        TextoDeArchivo.add( "dos" );
        TextoDeArchivo.add( "tres" );
        TextoDeArchivo.add( "cuatro" );
        TextoDeArchivo.add( "cinco" );
        TextoDeArchivo.add( "seis" );
        TextoDeArchivo.add( "siete" );
        TextoDeArchivo.add( "ocho" );
        TextoDeArchivo.add( "nueve" );
        TextoDeArchivo.add( "diez" );
        TextoDeArchivo.add( "once" );
        TextoDeArchivo.add( "doce" );
        TextoDeArchivo.add( "trece" );
        TextoDeArchivo.add( "catorce" );
        TextoDeArchivo.add( "quince" );
    }

}
```

```
public class TabsSetup extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
    String[] texto;
    List<Fragment> simpleTabList;
    public TabsSetup(List<Fragment> simpleTabList, FragmentManager fragmentManager) {
        super(fragmentManager);
        this.simpleTabList = simpleTabList;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return simpleTabList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 3;
    }
}
```

```
public class ContenidoFragment extends Fragment {
    public ContenidoFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.contenido_fragment, container, false);
        TextView txtTabsTitle = view.findViewById(R.id.texto_fragment);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            txtTabsTitle.setText(getArguments().getString("TextoDeLaNota"));
        }
        return view;
    }

    public Fragment newContenido(String texto) {
        com.paco.viewpagerpruebacon3.ContenidoFragment simpleTextFragment = new com.paco.viewpagerpruebacon3.ContenidoFragment();
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("TextoDeLaNota", texto);
        simpleTextFragment.setArguments(bundle);
        return simpleTextFragment;
    }

}
```